# Is it alright to use memcpy() to copy a struct that contains a pointer?

Tags: c++, struct, memcpy

I was thinking about this the other day and I am curious if this is a bad idea...
Lets say there is a structure that contains a pointer to a string array. 
Would the memcpy() copy the 'name' array pointer in the below example?
Edit: The std is inaccessible in this example.

```
struct charMap
{ 
  unsigned char * name;   
  unsigned char id;       
};
typedef struct charMap CharMapT;

class ABC
{
  public:
  ABC(){}
  void Function();
  CharMapT* structList;
}

void ABC::Function ()
{
  CharMapT list[] = 
  {
    {"NAME1", 1},
    {"NAME2", 2}, 
    {"NAME3", 3}
  };

  structList = new CharMapT[sizeof(list)];
  memcpy(structList, &list, sizeof(list));
}
```

Comment: For c++ code, might I suggest [std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead of `memcpy` and possibly [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of c style arrays?

Comment: And `std::string` instead of c style strings :)

Comment: This is called a shallow copy.

Comment: Can't use std lib. I'm in the embedded world.

Comment: @RLefevre: Not having access to a conformant c++ compiler (or having other reasons keeping you from writing standard c++) is something you might want to mention in your question.

Comment: Even in the embedded world you could surround yourself with a string class instead of a c-style string (you can write it yourself, but using a class is the way to go, there's no overhead in it). Vectors detto. (you need to keep track of the size of your array anyway...) Maybe you could consider a stripped-down version of stl.

Comment: If you are copying pointers to string literals you should be ok. If you start allocating name, then you will have the problem of ownership. Who will delete the string?, how others are informed about deletion...

Comment: Also note that you need a destructor (or you will leak memory)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several errors in the code presented, which I will talk about first, followed by my stock-diatribe of pointers vs. arrays.

```
struct charMap
{ 
  unsigned int * name;   
  unsigned int id;       
};
typedef struct charMap CharMapT;
```

This declares a structure type that includes a pointer to unsigned int as the first member (name) and an int as the second member (id). On a 32-bit system with default byte packing this will be **8 bytes** wide (32-bit pointer = 4bytes, 32-bit signed int=4bytes). If this is a 64-bit machine the pointers will be 8 bytes wide, the int still-likely 32-bits wide, making the structure size **12 bytes**.

**Questionable Code**

```
void ABC::Function ()
{
  CharMapT list[] = 
  {
    {"NAME1", 1},
    {"NAME2", 2}, 
    {"NAME3", 3}
  };

  structList = new CharMapT[sizeof(list)];
  memcpy(structList, &list, sizeof(list));
}
```

This allocates dynamic array of CharMapT structs. How many? More than you think. The `sizeof(list)` will return the byte-count of the `list[]` array. Since a CharMapT structure is 8 bytes wide (see above) this will 3 * 8, or **24 CharMapT items** (36 items if using 64-bit pointers).

We then `memcpy()` 24 **bytes** (or 36 bytes) from `list` (the `&` in `&list` is unecessary) to the newly allocated memory. this will copy over 3 CharMapT structures, leaving the other 21 we allocated untouched (beyond their initial default construction).

Note: you're initializing a `const char *` to a field declared as `unsigned int *`, so if this even compiled the fundamental data type would be different. Assuming you fixed your structure and change the pointer type to `const char *`, the addresses of the static string constants (the addresses of the "NAME" constants) somewhere in your const data segment will be assigned to the pointer variables of the elements in structList[0].name, structList[2].name, and structList[3].name respectively.

This will NOT copy the data pointed *to*. it will only copy the pointer *values*. If you want copies of the data then you must raw-allocate them (malloc, new, whatever).

Better still, use an `std::vector<CharMapT>`, use `std::string` for `CharMapT::name`, and use `std::copy()` to replicate the source (or even direct-assignment).

I hope that explains what you were looking for.

---

**Pointer vs. Array Diatribe**

**Never** confuse a pointer with an array. A pointer is a *variable* that *holds* an address. Just like an `int` variable hold an integer value, or a `char` variable holds a character type, the value held in a pointer is an address

An array is different. It is also a variable (obviously), but it cannot be an l-value, and nearly every place it is typically used a conversion happens. Conceptually that conversion results in a temporary pointer that points to the data type of the array, and holds the address of the first element. There are times when that concept does *not* happen (such as the applying the address-of operator).

```
void foo(const char * p)
{
}

char ar[] = "Hello, World!";
foo(ar); // passes 'ar', converted to `char*`, into foo. 
         // the parameter p in foo will *hold* this address
```

or this:

```
char ar[] = "Goodbye, World!";
const char *p = ar;  // ok. p now holds the address of first element in ar
++p;                 // ok. address in `p` changed to address (ar+1)
```

but not this:

```
char ar[] = "Goodbye, World!";
++ar; //  error. nothing to increment.
```

Comment: @RLefevre: if you take into consideration what WhosCraig said, you find your code rewritten in my answer.

Comment: Excellent post. You're the only one to also pick up on the fact that the new[] dramatically overallocates.

Comment: @EdS. a testimony to my boring life, i guess =P

Comment: @RLefevre glad it helped. Just remember that pointers are nothing more than another type of variable that holds a memory address of something, and you'll be fine. That ideology will mean a *lot* more when you start working with pointers-to-pointers (such as `char **p`, a pointer to a char-pointer).

Comment: Just a little nitpick: I believe on a 64-bit machine, `charMap` would be 16 bytes (assuming no packing) since there should be padding after the `unsigned int id`.

Answer (score 4):

It won't copy your actual data pointed by `name`. It will copy the pointer and you'll have 2 pointers to the same place in 2 objects (for each pair of objects in 2 arrays).

Comment: @RLefevre: Why unsigned?  Why mutable? It should be a `const char*`.

Comment: So, memcpy is copying the pointer address, not the actual 'name' data? This is probably bad because list[] is on the heap so the data would get lost, right?

Comment: @RLefevre: `list` is allocated with automatic storage duration, i.e., the *stack*, not the heap.  And yes, you now have dangling pointers which are invalid once the function returns.  You'll need to copy the array itself if you're stuck using C (this really isn't C++, more C with classes, assuming homework).

Comment: Thanks Ed (its been a long day... yes, the stack). So I take it the *name pointers in the *structList array are all dangling after Function() is completed?

Comment: @RLefevre: Yes.  `list` goes out of scope, so any references or pointers to it are invalid when the function returns.

Answer (score 3):

All you really need to know here is that `memcpy` will give you a bit for bit copy of the original.  So what you'll have is two pointers with the same value (i.e., an address) which refer to the same data.

On a side note, you have declared `name` as a pointer to `int`, which is of course wrong here.  It should be a `const char*`.  Also, as this is C++ and not C, you're better served by something like `std::copy` which won't break your code subtly if `charMap` someday becomes a complex type.  On the same note, prefer `std::string` instead of `const char*` in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `sizeof()` is wrong when calling `new`.  You are allocating an array of `CharMapT` elements.  You have to specify the number of elements, but you are specifying a byte count instead.  So you need to fix that:

```
structList = new CharMapT[sizeof(list) / sizeof(CharMapT)];
```

With that fixed, the result of the `memcpy()` will be that `structList` will contains an exact copy of the raw data that `list[]` contains.  That means that the `structList[N].name` pointers will contain the same values as the `list[N].name` pointers, and thus they will all be pointing at the same physical memory for the string values.

If you want to do a deep copy of the string values, you have to allocate them separately, eg:

```
void ABC::Function ()
{
    CharMapT list[] = 
    {
        {"NAME1", 1},
        {"NAME2", 2}, 
        {"NAME3", 3}
    };

    int num = sizeof(list) / sizeof(CharMapT);
    structList = new CharMapT[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        int len = strlen(list[i].name);
        structList[i].name = new char[len+1];
        strcpy(structList[i].name, list[i].name);
        structList[i].name[len] = 0;

        structList[i].id = list[i].id;
    }
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
        delete[] structList[i].name;
    delete[] structList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to @EdS.'s answer:

Your code is just much more **c++** than c-style c++ code if you do it like this:

```
#include<string>
#include<vector>

struct CharMap
{ 
  CharMap(const std::string& name, unsigned char id); // only needed if you don't use -std=c++11
  std::string name;   
  unsigned char id;       
};
CharMap::CharMap(const std::string& name, unsigned char id):
  name(name),
  id(id)
{}

class ABC
{
public:
  ABC(); // or ABC() = default; if you use -std=c++11
  void Function();
private:
  std::vector<CharMap> structList;
}

ABC::ABC(){} // not needed with -std=c++11

void ABC::Function ()
{
  // This works with -std=c++11:
  //structList = 
  //{
  //  {"NAME1", 1},
  //  {"NAME2", 2}, 
  //  {"NAME3", 3}
  //}; 

  // without c++11:
  structList = std::vector<CharMap>(3);
  structList[0] = CharMap("NAME1",1); // don't worry about copies, we have RVO (check wikipedia or SO)
  structList[1] = CharMap("NAME2",2);
  structList[2] = CharMap("NAME2",3);
}
```

Why not using `std::vector` for making an array? You can do that like this:

```
#include<vector>

std::vector<CharMapT> structList(list.size());
```

It is safer, too, avoiding using pointers decreases the chance of memory leaks or bugs arising due to wrongly using the `sizeof` operator.

I suppose you do not really want a structList, that has as many elements as the *memory size* of your list. (If list is double this could be many times more than the number of elements in your list.)

Also, `memcpy` is really not necessary, if list is also a vector (that is a c function really). You just do a simple assign operation:

```
structList = list; // given that list is a vector.
```

This will copy the elements like memcpy.